# Attack on ERC-777 smart contract and UniswapV2Pair resulting in 104 ETH liquidity drain

Tags: solidity, uniswap, reentrant-attacks, transferfrom, erc-777

My [ERC-777 smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd45740ab9ec920bedbd9bab2e863519e59731941) (Schnoodle, symbol SNOOD) was attacked yesterday resulting in the entire liquidity in the [UniswapV2Pair token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0f6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae) being drained (104 ETH). The attack was by way of an attacker contract that performed a [series of interactions](https://etherscan.io/address/0x273521f6582076a5fc54da9af9bfca5435ffe9ec/advanced#internaltx) with the liquidity token and my smart contract during its creation (txn [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9a6227ef97d7ce75732645bd604ef128bb5dfbc1bfbe0966ad1cd2870d45a20e)).

By clicking the  icon on the [list of internal transactions](https://etherscan.io/address/0x273521f6582076a5fc54da9af9bfca5435ffe9ec/advanced#internaltx), I can see the following input/output data:

```
Input:
0x022c0d9f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a3f13b802bf25f800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180ea08644b123d8a3f0eccf2a3b45a5820755380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080

Input:
0x0902f1ac
Output:
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a3f13b802bf25f8100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062ad7934

Input:
0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000000f6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae0000000000000000000000000000000000000000686558904b462764f122c4e1

Input:
0xfff6cae9

Input:
0x23b872dd0000000000000000000000000f6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae000000000000000000000000273521f6582076a5fc54da9af9bfca5435ffe9ec0000000000000000000000000000000000000000686558904b462764f122c4e1

Input:
0x70a082310000000000000000000000000f6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae
Output:
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000686558904b462764f122c4e2
```

I've deciphered this, and it translates to these function calls:

- **1. UniswapV2Pair.swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, to)**

  - amount0Out: 104047009087796436864 or 104.xxx...4 ETH
  - amount1Out: 0
  - to: 0x180ea08644b123d8a3f0eccf2a3b45a582075538 (message sender)
- **2. UniswapV2Pair.getReserves()**

  - **OUTPUT**

    - reserve0: 104047009087796436865 or 104.xxx...5 ETH
    - reserve1: 1 or 1E-18 SNOOD
    - blockTimestampLast: 1655535924
- **3. Schnoodle.transfer(recipient, amount)**

  - recipient: 0xf6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae (liquidity token)
  - amount: 32308960759206669952686933217 or 32.3b SNOOD
- **4. UniswapV2Pair.sync**
- **5. Schnoodle.transferFrom(holder, recipient, amount)**

  - holder: 0xf6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae (liquidity token)
  - recipient: 0x273521f6582076a5fc54da9af9bfca5435ffe9ec (attacker contract)
  - amount: 32308960759206669952686933217 or 32.3b SNOOD
- **6. Schnoodle.balanceOf(account)**

  - account: 0xf6b0960d2569f505126341085ed7f0342b67dae (liquidity token)
  - **OUTPUT**

    - 32308960759206669952686933217 or 32.3b SNOOD

They all happened at the same second, so they're not listed in the correct order on Etherscan. But it's clear that the output of #2 (`getReserves`) is used as parameter `amount0Out` of #1 (`swap`) albeit with 1 subtracted which is interesting. And the output of #6 (`balanceOf`) is used as parameter `amount` of #3 and #5 (`transfer` and `transferFrom`).

So, it seems that the attacker contract gets the SNOOD balance of the liquidity token, and the amount of ETH in the liquidity token reserves, then does the following at the same time:

- `transferFrom` to transfer all SNOOD from the liquidity token to the attacker contract
- `transfer` to transfer all SNOOD from the message sender to the liquidity token
- `swap` to swap SNOOD for 104 ETH to the message sender

At no point does the message sender receive any SNOOD. Yet it is able to transfer SNOOD to the liquidity token. I am unable to figure this out further. I decompiled the byte code using [this decompiler](https://ethervm.io/decompile) and the attacker contract address (0x273521F6582076a5FC54da9Af9bFca5435ffE9eC), but it's outside of my comfort zone. Could this be a reentrancy attack on the SNOOD or the UniswapV2Pair contract?

I've done some research, and I found that there was previously a reentrancy vulnerability for ERC-777 tokens using Uniswap v1. See [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/111480/63971) which links to the [exploit example on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/exploit-uniswap), and also the [Uniswap whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper.pdf) which indicates that the vulnerability was patched in Uniswap v2.

What I would like to know is, how did this attack take place, where is the vulnerability? And how do I protect against it? If this is an vulnerability in the SNOOD code, then how do I fix it? If it's a vulnerability in the UniswapV2Pair code related to ERC-777 tokens which is what SNOOD is, then I guess I would have to change my contract to ERC-20, or use UniswapV3Pair, or another DEX altogether.

There is also a $1500 bounty (negotiable) available for solving this vulnerability which can be viewed [here](https://app.dework.xyz/schnoodle-dao-1/schnoodle-dao-6?taskId=6f97bcc5-5946-4a67-a6bb-a360f179db86) via our Dework platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your error is [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xeac2a259f3ebb8fd1097aeccaa62e73b6e43d5bf#code#F2#L58). Typically this kind of computation is done using fixed-point arithmetic or using a `reflection * totalSupply / reflectedSupply` calculation. In the case of transaction 0x9a6227ef97d7ce75732645bd604ef128bb5dfbc1bfbe0966ad1cd2870d45a20e , during the call to `_spendAllowance`, the `_getStandardAmount` call returns `0`, even though the amount being transferred is significant. It's hard to tell what the intent of this code is, but the result is that the reflected amount isn't converted to a token amount, but is instead simply set to zero because `_getReflectRate` returns a large value. As a result, even though the UniswapV2 trading pair does not have an allowance set, the attacker is able to `transferFrom` the total balance of the pair to their attack contract. Subsequently, the attacker calls `sync` to force the pair to take up its new, vastly-decreased balance as the reserve. After that, it's a simple matter of swapping the stolen SNOOD tokens for the WETH left in the pair.

Comment: To put it another way, your `transferFrom` is broken and lets anyone transfer anyone's tokens.

Comment: Thank you for this reply! Much appreciated. To explain, the `ERC777Upgradeable` base contract stores all reflected values which are much larger representations of the "standard" values stored in the concrete contract (`SchnoodleV9Base`). `_getReflectedAmount` and `_getStandardAmount` converts between the two using the ratio of the reflected total supply and the standard total supply. All overrides are simply to serve this conversion purpose. But it seems `_spendAllowance` may be converting the wrong way - it should use `_getReflectedAmount`. Would this be your surmise, too?

Comment: Yes, it would seem that it's converting the wrong way. My recommendation here is that `_spendAllowance` should not convert at all. Allowances are denominated in tokens, not reflection, therefore the token-denominated value passed to `_spendAllowance` should remain token-denominated and never be converted into a reflection

Comment: The OpenZeppelin base contract (`ERC777Upgradeable`) stores all balances as reflection amounts. So, the `_spendAllowance` function in the base contract must also be reflection amounts. And therefore, conversions must take place to be the actual token amounts that are exposed outside of the contract. That's how I've used OpenZeppelin Contracts. It's a unique way to use them, but it served my purpose. Therefore, changing `_spendAllowance` to use `_getReflectedAmount` will fix the problem, and therefore the vulnerability. Can you confirm you could see the attack vector you described in the logs?

Comment: I recommend against doing that. Allowances should be *stored* token-denominated, not reflection-denominated. This probably works *most* of the time because most users will set "infinite" allowances so it doesn't matter. But if another DeFi protocol depends on allowances being consistent, it will break. It would be surprising if allowance increased with balances due to the reflection mechanism.

Comment: I arrived at my conclusion by looking at the call trace on tenderly, so yes I do see the attack I described in the logs

Comment: And lastly, you have a rounding error problem in `_getReflectedAmount` and `_getStandardAmount`. `_getReflectedAmount` should compute something like `amount * super.totalSupply() / totalSupply()` and `_getStandardAmount` should compute `amount * totalSupply() / super.totalSupply()`. If those overflow, use `FullMath` https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/FullMath.sol . Once again, this *mostly* doesn't matter, but as we can see in the case of your use of `_getStandardAmount` in `_spendAllowance`, it *can* be catastrophic

Comment: 1. I understand. So, there may be a DeFi protocol that stores allowances, and may fail if an allowance changed? But this wouldn't necessarily cause an exploit, perhaps at worst a failing (reverting) function call, right? 2. I wasn't aware of Tenderly. Thanks for that! 3. So, this only matters if there is a vulnerability like the one I have, right? If I'd used `FullMath`, are you saying this vulnerability might not have been exploitable?

Comment: 1. It's hard to anticipate/speculate what might happen with other DeFi protocols. I don't know of any examples where it would cause an exploit, but I also can't say that such a protocol doesn't exist.

3. No, this is on top of the vulnerability that was exploited. Because you're computing the ratio and then *separately* scaling the value by the ratio, you'll end up with wrongly-rounded results.

I've sent you a friend request on Discord. Let's continue this discussion there.

Comment: Thanks - I accepted and sent you a message. The community are also very happy with your findings: https://t.me/SchnoodleDAO/77068

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's useful now, but I just dug into this and found the problem.

Everything Duncan addressed is correct, but the question remains:

*WHY does _getStandardAmount return zero?*

The formula is correct — it's taking totalSupply() / totalSupply on ERC777 contract, which equals the # minted. Total supply divided by number minted should always be greater than or equal to 1 (as long as we haven't minted more than supply).

The answer is in the `initialize()` function. You set the totalSupply to equal initialTokens * 10 ** decimnals(), but then you proceed to mint `MAX - (MAX % totalSupply())`, which is a massive number.

As a result, the number minted WAY outweighs the totalSupply on the implementation contract, which results in the 0 return value.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: You've misunderstood the algorithm which is a reflective algorithm. `_getStandardAmount` does not take `totalSupply() / _totalSupply`. It takes `reflectedAmount` which is always a large amount. This is then divided by the ratio of the reflected total supply to the total supply (`super.totalSupply() / _totalSupply`) which is a large amount also. So the orders of magnitude of the divisor and the dividend are equivalent. However, this was not the question, and you should not be asking a question as an Answer.